# Why is Excel VBA only accepting a relative R1C1 reference in this array formula?

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas, excel-r1c1-notation

I am trying to add this line of code to my VBA. It adds an array formula to a range of cells:

```
str_Formula = "=INDEX(rng_List,MATCH(1,--(RC1>=rng_A)*--(RC1<=rng_B),0))"
rng_Formula.FormulaArray = str_Formula
```

For some reason, the formula only computes if I use a relative R1C1 reference (RC[-22]) instead. If I use the absolute form above, then it tries to use the value of cell RC1 (in A1 reference notation).

Is there a way I can force VBA to read RC1 as an R1C1 reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way I can force VBA to read RC1 as an R1C1 reference.

From Scott Craner above:

> "Because there is a column `RC` you cannot do an absolute column and relative row without the `[]` after the R. You can do an absolute row and relative column `R1C` and it will work, but it will first try A1 and if that works it will use it, otherwise it will try R1C1."